# How to rotate a marker based on a value

Tags: carto, cartocss

I wanted to know if it is possible to make a turn for a point with a defined image (arrow example) depending on the attribute of a field that reflects the angle in degrees.
I want to represent the direction of the wind for these three meteorological stations. In the three I have the addresses (220,230,240 ...) but I do not know if there is any way to rotate the layer in cartocss.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [use `marker-transform` CartoCSS property](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties/#marker-transform-functions) in combination with `rotate` function, and also setting the `marker-type` as `arrow`:

`marker-type: arrow;
  marker-transform: rotate(([wdir]-90),0,0);`

[image]

You can check a beautiful example done by a colleague [here](https://team.carto.com/u/abel/builder/e93ba2cc-321f-11e6-b8ed-0e31c9be1b51/embed).